# Ivy dependency conf map wildcard

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, ivy

In an ivy dependency,

**Q1.**
What is the difference between

> conf="runtime->compile"

vs

> conf="runtime->compile(*)"

What does the extra bracketed wildcard do?

**Q2.**

What does the following do?

> conf="compile->compile(*)"

Isn't it a cyclical/self dependency? What is the point of mapping a conf back to itself?

Comment: Note: I tagged the question with [maven] because the ivy conf is mapping to maven pom scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The brackets are a [fallback](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/2.1.0/ivyfile/dependency.html):

> since 1.3 a fallback mechanism can be used when you are not sure that
>   the dependency will have the required conf. You can indicate to ivy
>   that you want one configuration, but if it isn't present, use another
>   one.  The syntax for specifying this adds the fallback conf between
>   parenthesis right after the required conf.  For instance,
>
> `test->runtime(default)`
>   means that in the `test` configuration of the
>   module the
>   `runtime`
>   conf of the dependency is required, but if doesn't
>   exist, it will use the
>   `default`
>   conf instead. If default conf doesn't
>   exist then it will be considered as an error. Note that the
>   * wildcard can be used as fallback conf.

For Question2:
a conf is always read like:

```
ConfFromThisFile -> ConfFromDependency
```

So

```
compile->compile
```

will map the `compile` configuration of the dependency to the `compile` configuration of this file. It is no cycle. The bracket says: If `compile` does not exist in the dependency then use `*`.

See the Configuration Mapping Section of the [ivy documentation for dependencies](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/2.1.0/ivyfile/dependency.html).

Answer (score 1):

This syntax is for dependency fallback. `runtime->compile` means that the runtime configuration depends on the compile config. The compile config must be present or Ivy will report an error. However, `runtime->compile(*)` will try the compile configuration first to satisfy dependencies. But if compile doesn't exist, it will try all the other configurations. See the Configurations mapping section of the [Ivy docs](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/ivyfile/dependency.html) for more info.

Based on that, `compile->compile(*)` would indicate that compile needs any (all?) configurations. I am guessing that `compile->(*)` isn't valid syntax so the extra `compile`  guarantees the fallback is used since `compile` isn't defined until after the configuration XML stanza is complete.

Note that it's not clear from the documentation if `(*)` means 'any' or 'all' configurations. So, I am not sure if Ivy will stop at the first configuration that matches all dependencies (if there is one) or if it brings in all the other configurations in a union.